# Yii::app()->db not giving any response

Tags: database, yii

I am using sqlite in yii. In **index.php** page I am using

```
Yii::app()->db
```

to check whether the db is connected or not. But whatever database name I put in 'connectionString' in the main.php file -

for example:

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'sqlite:c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\qdr\\protected\\data\\abcd.db',
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
),
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'sqlite:c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\qdr\\protected\\data\\jklm.db',
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
),
```

It does not show any error though I am changing and using random names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a major issue. Actually this is because whatever name you put in the 'connectionString', yii automatically creates a database with that name. so Yii::app()->db does not give any error. Thanks